# Different type of robots txt used in website why?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Hello guys i reviewing many website but i found a diifrent type of robots txt will any one please help me to know that why this type robots txt used

what is the advantage of this and disadvantage of this....

```
User-Agent: Googlebot-Images
Disallow: 

User-agent: OmniExplorer_Bot
Disallow: 

User-agent: FreeFind
Disallow: 

User-agent: BecomeBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Nutch
Disallow: 

User-agent: Jetbot/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: Jetbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebVac
Disallow: 

User-agent: Stanford
Disallow: 

User-agent: naver
Disallow: 

User-agent: dumbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Hatena Antenna
Disallow: 

User-agent: grub-client
Disallow: 

User-agent: grub
Disallow: 

User-agent: looksmart
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebZip
Disallow: 

User-agent: larbin
Disallow: 

User-agent: b2w/0.1
Disallow: 

User-agent: Copernic
Disallow: 

User-agent: psbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Python-urllib
Disallow: 

User-agent: NetMechanic
Disallow: 

User-agent: URL_Spider_Pro
Disallow: 

User-agent: CherryPicker
Disallow: 

User-agent: EmailCollector
Disallow: 

User-agent: EmailSiphon
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebBandit
Disallow: 

User-agent: EmailWolf
Disallow: 

User-agent: ExtractorPro
Disallow: 

User-agent: CopyRightCheck
Disallow: 

User-agent: Crescent
Disallow: 

User-agent: SiteSnagger
Disallow: 

User-agent: ProWebWalker
Disallow: 

User-agent: CheeseBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: LNSpiderguy
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla
Disallow: 

User-agent: mozilla
Disallow: 

User-agent: mozilla/3
Disallow: 

User-agent: mozilla/4
Disallow: 

User-agent: mozilla/5
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows NT)
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 95)
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 98)
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows XP)
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 4.0; Windows 2000)
Disallow: 

User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: 

User-agent: ia_archiver/1.6
Disallow: 

User-agent: Alexibot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Teleport
Disallow: 

User-agent: TeleportPro
Disallow: 

User-agent: Stanford Comp Sci
Disallow: 

User-agent: MIIxpc
Disallow: 

User-agent: Telesoft
Disallow: 

User-agent: Website Quester
Disallow: 

User-agent: moget/2.1
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebZip/4.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebStripper
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebSauger
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebCopier
Disallow: 

User-agent: NetAnts
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mister PiX
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebAuto
Disallow: 

User-agent: TheNomad
Disallow: 

User-agent: WWW-Collector-E
Disallow: 

User-agent: RMA
Disallow: 

User-agent: libWeb/clsHTTP
Disallow: 

User-agent: asterias
Disallow: 

User-agent: httplib
Disallow: 

User-agent: turingos
Disallow: 

User-agent: spanner
Disallow: 

User-agent: InfoNaviRobot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Harvest/1.5
Disallow: 

User-agent: Bullseye/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; BullsEye; Windows 95)
Disallow: 

User-agent: Crescent Internet ToolPak HTTP OLE Control v.1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: CherryPickerSE/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: CherryPickerElite/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebBandit/3.50
Disallow: 

User-agent: NICErsPRO
Disallow: 

User-agent: Microsoft URL Control - 5.01.4511
Disallow: 

User-agent: DittoSpyder
Disallow: 

User-agent: Foobot
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebmasterWorldForumBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: SpankBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: BotALot
Disallow: 

User-agent: lwp-trivial/1.34
Disallow: 

User-agent: lwp-trivial
Disallow: 

User-agent: http://www.WebmasterWorld.com bot
Disallow: 

User-agent: BunnySlippers
Disallow: 

User-agent: Microsoft URL Control - 6.00.8169
Disallow: 

User-agent: URLy Warning
Disallow: 

User-agent: Wget/1.6
Disallow: 

User-agent: Wget/1.5.3
Disallow: 

User-agent: Wget
Disallow: 

User-agent: LinkWalker
Disallow: 

User-agent: cosmos
Disallow: 

User-agent: moget
Disallow: 

User-agent: hloader
Disallow: 

User-agent: humanlinks
Disallow: 

User-agent: LinkextractorPro
Disallow: 

User-agent: Offline Explorer
Disallow: 

User-agent: Mata Hari
Disallow: 

User-agent: LexiBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Web Image Collector
Disallow: 

User-agent: The Intraformant
Disallow: 

User-agent: True_Robot/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: True_Robot
Disallow: 

User-agent: BlowFish/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: http://www.SearchEngineWorld.com bot
Disallow: 

User-agent: http://www.WebmasterWorld.com bot
Disallow: 

User-agent: JennyBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: MIIxpc/4.2
Disallow: 

User-agent: BuiltBotTough
Disallow: 

User-agent: ProPowerBot/2.14
Disallow: 

User-agent: BackDoorBot/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: toCrawl/UrlDispatcher
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebEnhancer
Disallow: 

User-agent: suzuran
Disallow: 

User-agent: VCI WebViewer VCI WebViewer Win32
Disallow: 

User-agent: VCI
Disallow: 

User-agent: Szukacz/1.4
Disallow: 

User-agent: QueryN Metasearch
Disallow: 

User-agent: Openfind data gathere
Disallow: 

User-agent: Openfind
Disallow: 

User-agent: Xenu's Link Sleuth 1.1c
Disallow: 

User-agent: Xenu's
Disallow: 

User-agent: Zeus
Disallow: 

User-agent: RepoMonkey Bait & Tackle/v1.01
Disallow: 

User-agent: RepoMonkey
Disallow: 

User-agent: Microsoft URL Control
Disallow: 

User-agent: Openbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: URL Control
Disallow: 

User-agent: Zeus Link Scout
Disallow: 

User-agent: Zeus 32297 Webster Pro V2.9 Win32
Disallow: 

User-agent: Webster Pro
Disallow: 

User-agent: EroCrawler
Disallow: 

User-agent: LinkScan/8.1a Unix
Disallow: 

User-agent: Keyword Density/0.9
Disallow: 

User-agent: Kenjin Spider
Disallow: 

User-agent: Iron33/1.0.2
Disallow: 

User-agent: Bookmark search tool
Disallow: 

User-agent: GetRight/4.2
Disallow: 

User-agent: FairAd Client
Disallow: 

User-agent: Gaisbot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Aqua_Products
Disallow: 

User-agent: Radiation Retriever 1.1
Disallow: 

User-agent: WebmasterWorld Extractor
Disallow: 

User-agent: Flaming AttackBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Oracle Ultra Search
Disallow: 

User-agent: MSIECrawler
Disallow: 

User-agent: PerMan
Disallow: 

User-agent: searchpreview
Disallow: 

User-agent: sootle
Disallow: 

User-agent: es
Disallow: 

User-agent: Enterprise_Search/1.0
Disallow: 

User-agent: Enterprise_Search
Disallow:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands, the file does not do anything useful at all. It actually does exactly the same thing as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

An empty `Disallow:` means "allow everything", so you could also get the same effect by using an empty robots.txt file, or by not having any robots.txt file at all. There is no need to list individual user-agents if you are planning to allow everyone to crawl everything.

I can only speculate as to why this file exists. Maybe it originally had:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

as the last two lines, (to block any crawler not explicitly listed above) and then later someone removed these two lines to allow everything. Or maybe the person who wrote the file mistakenly thought that `Disallow:` meant "block everything".